# Scope of variables (Hoisting) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

One of my friends was taking an online quiz and he asked me this question which I could not answer.

```
var global = false;

function test() {
  global = true;
  return false;
  function global() {}
}

console.log(global); // says false (As expected)
test();
console.log(global); // says false (Unexpected: should be true)
```

If we assume that functions are hoisted at the top along with var variables, let's try this one.

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    var foo = 11;
}

bar();
console.log(foo); //says 1 (But should be 11) Why 1 this time ??
```

Here is a [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/tope/1/edit?html,js,console,output) and [JSBIN Demo2](http://jsbin.com/tope/4/edit?js,console,output) to play with.

PS: If we remove `function global() {}` from `test()`, then it runs fine. Can somebody help me understand why is this happening ?

Comment: Im not adding an answer to the edit as the answer from @SLaks still applies. `var foo = 11` IS `11` in the local scope to that function. `foo = 10` is ignored and `function foo()` is still creating a local scoped variable foo as well as `var foo`

Comment: bar() returns the function

Comment: @DavidBarker Yeah I understand it now. Thanks for your nice add-on to Slak's answer.

Comment: Notice that the `global` variable in the function is actually local…

Comment: You can also step through the process via Chrome dev tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var` statements and function declaration statements are "hoisted" to the top of their enclosing scope.
Therefore, the `function global(){}` in your function creates a local `global` name.

Assigning to `global` inside your functions binds to this local name.  Here's how you can "rewrite" it using hoisting to understand how the compiler sees it:

```
function test() {
    var global = function() {};   // hoisted; 'global' now local
    global = true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης: No; that's what hoisting means.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Functions assigned in the way the OP has written, will always be hoisted as answer says.

Comment: @^ That is what I am thinking.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Great answer, SLaks; I added a compiler "re-written" function to make it more clear to the uninitiated...I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @SLaks Gotcha..Now I get your answer..Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης Some years ago this article was an eye opener for me, I just wanted to share ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the second part of your question,

> If we assume that functions are hoisted at the top along with var variables
>
> ```
> bar();
> console.log(foo); //says 1 (But should be 11) Why 1 this time ??
> ```

You should try `console.log(bar()); console.log(foo);` instead. However, what hoisting does to your function is this:

```
function bar() {
    var foo;
    function foo() {}
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    foo = 11;
}
```

So you should expect to get the function returned, since your variable assignments are after the `return` statement. And both the `var` and the function declaration make `foo` a local variable, so the global `foo = 1` is never changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. +1 I get it now. The article by wared really helped me. I din't know such thing like hoisting exists in JS world +1